# Solution of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm not able to give a general solution of this pde:

$$ {\partial \over \partial t} {\Phi(x,t)}={k^2\Phi(x,t)^2}{\partial^2 \over \partial x^2}{\Phi(x,t)}$$
Can someone help me?

Comment: This looks rather difficult, as it is a nonlinear PDE.

Comment: I found one! how about $\Phi=ax+b$?

Comment: Thanks yohBS, but I don't see any dependence from the time t

Comment: @yohBS: and it is far from a general solution ;-)

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: nonlinear PDEs are pretty hard (apart from some well-known integrable examples). Thus, I would recommend to give some additional motivation: where does this equation arise? why are you interested in it?

Comment: @Fabian: it's a Fick diffusion equation with a diffusion coefficient proportional to the square of the concentration itself.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: rather unfortunately your description ("Fick diffusion equation with a diffusion coefficient proportional to the square of the concentration") does not give any more information than the equation itself.

Comment: Have you tried checking one of the references like _Handbook of Differential Equations_?

Comment: A side comment: I don't like describing that as a diffusion equation. Diffusion should conserve total particle number, which is $N(t) = \int \Phi(x,t) dx$. In your model $\partial_t N(t) < 0$ strictly assuming the particle density $\Phi \geq 0$. Somehow you are losing particles.

Comment: @Willie Wong: You are right. In fact this is a diffusion equation of atoms doping a particular kind of material in which part of the atoms form a bound with the material itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my try. It's a standard trick that is used in physics, but I can't guarantee that the solution is the most general. Actually, I'm certain that it is not.

First of all, define $\tilde t = t k^2$ so that the equation does not have $k$ anymore. Now guess an ansatz of the form $\Phi=X(x)T(t)$, where $X$ is a function of $x$ ***only*** and $T$ is a function of $T$ ***only***. Plugging that into the equation yields

$$X(x) T'(t)-T(t)^3 X(x)^2 X''(x)=0$$

which can be transformed, assuming all $T,X$ do not vanish to

$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)^3}=X(x)''X(x)$$

Since the left hand side depends on $t$ only, and the right one on $x$, they both must be a constant, which we'll denote by $g$. So you need to solve the two ODE's:

$$\begin{align}
T'&=g T^3\\
X''&=\frac{1}{X}
\end{align}
$$

The solution of the first equation is 
$$T=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2(g t+C)}}$$
where $C$ is an integration constant. If you choose it negative enough then $T$ will be real. The solution of the $X$ equation is a bit more difficult, but Mathematica finds one:
$$X=A^{-2} e^{ \operatorname{InverseErf}\left[\pm i\sqrt{A \frac{2g}{\pi } (x+B)^2}\right]^2}$$
where $A,B$ are integration constants. Is this any good?

Comment: The problem with separation of variables is that, while for linear equations one can often end up writing the general solution as a linear superposition of special separation of variables solutions, for nonlinear equations this class of solutions is only representative of some special cases.

Comment: I am well aware of that, and I wrote explicitly that this is not the most general solution.

Comment: @yohBs: Ok. I accept your answer, but as you said this solution is not the general solution. Thanks

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Thx. By the way, if your equation really describes "diffusion with a diffusion coefficient proportional to the square of the concentration itself", then it should read $$\partial_t \Phi=\nabla\cdot\left(\Phi^2\vec\nabla\Phi\right)$$ Written like that it will conserve the particle number.